# Change behavior/color of function depending on link

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have sliding-middle-out:hover:after display a different background color depending on the link that is hovered over. I assume there's a way to attach an id# to the function and have it display the color depending on the id that I attached to the html, but I can't figure it out.

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #232526;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #232526, #414345);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #232526, #414345);
  margin: 0em;
}
a {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}
#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: : 0;
  height: 40px;
  background: #e4e6e5;
  background-color: rgba(228, 230, 229, .8);
  border-top: solid transparent 5px;
  z-index: 250;
  text-align: center;
}
#navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 2% 0 2%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #666666;
}
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 135px;
  background: #e4e6e5;
  background-color: rgba(228, 230, 229, .8);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  border-top: solid transparent 5px;
  z-index: 250;
}
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: .5em;
}
.wrap {
  display: table;
  height: 100px;
  width: 360px;
}
#wrap_left {
  text-align: left;
}
#wrap_left a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 2% 0 2%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #888888;
}
#wrap_right {
  text-align: right;
}
.linebreak {
  padding-top: 3px;
}
#content {
  padding: 50px 0 140px 100px;
}
#sliding-middle-out {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
#sliding-middle-out:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
#sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  background: grey;
}
.material-icons.md-14 {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <a id="sliding-middle-out" href="Home.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">home</i>Home</a>
  <a id="sliding-middle-out" href="Warrior.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">delete_forever</i>Warrior</a>
  <a id="sliding-middle-out" href="Druid.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">spa</i>Druid</a>
  <a id="sliding-middle-out" href="Priest.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">wifi</i>Priest</a>
  <a id="sliding-middle-out" href="Paladin.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">star_half</i>Paladin</a>
  <a id="sliding-middle-out" href="Hunter.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">my_location</i>Hunter</a>
  <a id="sliding-middle-out" href="Mage.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">whatshot</i>Mage</a>
  <a id="sliding-middle-out" href="Shaman.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">nature_people</i>Shaman</a>
  <a id="sliding-middle-out" href="Warlock.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">person_outline</i>Warlock</a>
  <a id="sliding-middle-out" href="Rogue.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">visibility_off</i>Rogue</a>
  <a id="sliding-middle-out" href="Minions.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">keyboard_arrow_up</i>Minions</a>
  <a id="sliding-middle-out" href="Spells.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">keyboard_arrow_down</i>Spells</a>
</div>
<!-- navbar -->
<div id="content">
  <a href="../Cards/1/Jade_Idol.html">
    <img src="../Cards/1/Jade_Idol_S.png">
  </a>
  <a href="../Cards/1/Mark_of_the_Lotus.html">
    <img src="../Cards/1/Mark_of_the_Lotus_S.png">
  </a>
  <a href="../Cards/3/Celestial_Dreamer.html">
    <img src="../Cards/3/Celestial_Dreamer_S.png">
  </a>
  <a href="../Cards/3/Jade_Blossom.html">
    <img src="../Cards/3/Jade_Blossom_S.png">
  </a>
  <a href="../Cards/3/Pilfered_Power.html">
    <img src="../Cards/3/Pilfered_Power_S.png">
  </a>
  <a href="../Cards/4/Jade_Spirit.html">
    <img src="../Cards/4/Jade_Spirit_S.png">
  </a>
  <a href="../Cards/5/Lotus_Agents.html">
    <img src="../Cards/5/Lotus_Agents_S.png">
  </a>
  <a href="../Cards/5/Lunar_Visions.html">
    <img src="../Cards/5/Lunar_Visions_S.png">
  </a>
  <a href="../Cards/5/Virmen_Sensei.html">
    <img src="../Cards/5/Virmen_Sensei_S.png">
  </a>
  <a href="../Cards/6/Aya_Blackpaw.html">
    <img src="../Cards/6/Aya_Blackpaw_S.png">
  </a>
  <a href="../Cards/6/Jade_Behemoth.html">
    <img src="../Cards/6/Jade_Behemoth_S.png">
  </a>
  <a href="../Cards/10/Kun_the_Forgotten_King.html">
    <img src="../Cards/10/Kun_the_Forgotten_King_S.png">
  </a>
</div>
<!-- content -->
<center>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="inline">
      <div class="wrap">
        <div id="wrap_right">
          <font color="888888" size="4%">CARDSPOILER.COM</font>
          <br>
          <font color="9B764C" size="3%">Freedom to know</font>
          <p></p>
          <font size="2%" color="666666">We are here to bring you visual, leaked spoilers for all of the cards you love within a simple gallery setting.</font>
          <br>
          <font color="#333333">
                <a href="mailto:help@cardspoiler.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:#9B764C;font-size:70%;">CONTACT US</a>
                <a href="../../Privacy_Policy.html" style="text-decoration:none;color:#9B764C;font-size:70%;">PRIVACY POLICY</a>
              </font>
        </div>
        <!-- inline -->
      </div>
      <!-- wrap -->
    </div>
    <!-- wrap_left -->
    <div class="inline">
      <div class="wrap">
        <div id="wrap_left">
          <td><a href="MSoG.html">Mean Streets of Gadgetzan</a>
          </td>
          <br>
          <td><a href="ONiK.html">One Night in Karazhan</a>
          </td>
          <br>
          <td><a href="WotOG.html">Whispers of the Old Gods</a>
          </td>
          <br>
          <td><a href="tLoE.html">The League of Explorers</a>
          </td>
          <br>
          <td><a href="TGT.html">The Grand Tournament</a>
          </td>
          <br>
          <td><a href="BrM.html">Blackrock Mountain</a>
          </td>
          <br>
        </div>
        <!-- inline -->
      </div>
      <!-- wrap -->
    </div>
    <!-- wrap_left -->
  </div>
  <!-- footer -->
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: Leaving aside the fact that you should never set the same id for multiple objects, you could have a look at the css attribute selector http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Is there any way to do this without having to copy the entire css of sliding-middle-out and just slightly changing the name and background-color?

Comment: you might be able to add something like  #sliding-middle-out[id=yourId]:after {background-color: #FF0000 !important; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like is was said in the comments, IDs **must** be unique.

You should change `#sliding-middle-out` to `.sliding-middle-out` and use it as a class and then add an id to each of those elements.

Something like:

html:

```
<a id="home" class="sliding-middle-out" href="Home.html"><i class="material-icons md-14">home</i>Home</a>
```

css:

```
#home.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  background-color: blue;
}
```